How to type iota subscript in ancient Greek using ibus with m17n
The m17n ancient Greek language input method works very well, including an almost complete set of diacritics. They are activated by typing the vowel followed by the modifier, such as / for acute accent, ' for smooth breathing and so on. However I have been unable to find the modifier for the iota subscript. Does anyone know how this is done? There are of course work-arounds, but the others work so smoothly, surely this one should as well.

The answer, I have just discovered, is upper case 'J'. So typing wJ produces ῳ .
